# Why can't the entities enter closed houses/buildings?

Tags: plot-explanation, bird-box

In [***Bird Box***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2737304/), why can't the entities/monsters enter the closed houses/ building by breaking the window/door?

In one of the scenes where a small group went out in car for supply run, it was seen that entities/monsters could shake the car, then why can't they break the window/doors.

Physical powers as shown in the movie:

- Shake big objects (Cars)
- Make trees shake (big gush of wind) when they pass by (or run)

Comment: It's never explained further in the movie, so it was not really important to the plot.

Comment: My guess (hence comment) is because It's kind of like the Medusa concept: as long as you don't look at her, she has no power over you. She can only try to coerce you to look at her. Think about the last scene where they're in the woods. The entities are practically on top of her, but they can't physically hurt her. They simply keep trying to get inside her mind and coerce her to remove her blindfold so they can kill her.

Comment: This could be one possibility.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan That was my theory too. But that still doesn't explain why, as Ankush asked, the entities couldn't enter the house and coerce them from inside.

Comment: I should have added in my comment that the entities can clearly manipulate objects (brush aside trees, cause a car to shake a little), but can’t flat out physically make contact with people. And, how do we know they didn’t make the car SEEM to shake, or the trees SEEM to move? These entities can screw with people’s minds, make them hear what they want them to hear and feel what they want them to feel. They’re there, but trying to make people panic into seeing them. Short of literally being able to bust into structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They can enter, but aren't strong enough to break down a door.

The creatures don't seem able to pass through barriers, like doors or barred windows. However, in the novel, they enter open rooms and houses.

> Malorie takes a dog while searching a bar/nightclub in the neighborhood for audio equipment. While Malorie searches the bar blindfolded, one of the creatures is inside and she hears the dog go insane.

The movie depicts the creatures quite differently.

> A creature is inside the room with Malorie and Olympia when they're giving birth. That's when Olympia see it, not like in the film where she sees it from outside the window. The film did some REALLY stupid stuff with the creatures. They don't shake trees, make leaves levitate or appear to you as your worst fear or dead loved one. They don't speak to you in voices either. They seem to just... exist. It's almost as if they don't even know what their effect is. They don't open doors but will go through open doors, though. They don't even seem actively malicious. A creature almost takes Malorie's blindfold off when she's on the river. It pulls the blindfold from her face and she puts her hands on the blindfold and says, "This is mine" and after a tense moment, the creature leaves.

In the movie, the creatures have this presence and seem to control wind. Hence cars shaking, leaves flying, hairs raising, etc. That is not enough to break down a house door.

---

Disclaimer: I haven't read the novel, I'm quoting comments from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/af13re/in_the_movie_birdbox_seeing_as_animals_arent/).